# How to convert string to array (int and string array).?

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

How can I get the String and the int values from a String like this : `"a:10,b:15,c:20,d:30"`

```
String mixedString = "a:10,b:15,c:20,d:30";
String requiredArray1[] = [a,b,c,d];
int requiredArray2[] = [10,15,20,20];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop your String and test your String one by one:

**First**

You need to split your String to :

```
String myString = "a:10,b:15,c:20,d:30";
//split the String to get only the Strings and int in your case you need to split with , and :

String mixedString[] = myString.split(":|\\,");
```

**Second**

Test If the String is Integer then return true and insert it to the array of Integers, else Insert it to the array of Strings:

```
public static boolean test(String s){
    try{
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here how your program should look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "a:10,b:15,c:20,d:30";
    String mixedString[] = myString.split(":|\\,");
    String requiredArray1[] = new String[mixedString.length];
    int requiredArray2[] = new int[mixedString.length];
    int s = 0;
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mixedString.length; i++) {
        if (!test(mixedString[i])) {
            requiredArray1[s] = mixedString[i];
            s++;
        } else {
            requiredArray2[n] = Integer.parseInt(mixedString[i]);
            n++;
        }
    }
}

public static boolean test(String s) {
    try {
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your mixed String is as you show in your post where every alpha character is **always** followed by a colon delimiter (:) and then a string representation of a numerical value, you really don't need an additional method to test for whether or not a numerical value is there. You simply know its there just as you know there is a alpha value there as well...or...maybe you don't and maybe you should test for the alpha as well. You don't specify either way within your post what different possibilities might exist within the mixed string. Therefore, we can assume that:

Every alpha section is delimited with a colon (:) and then followed by a string representation of a numerical value which so far does indeed appear to be Integer. This is then followed by a comma (,) delimiter and yet another colon delimited alpha/numerical pair.

```
String mixedString = "a:10,b:15,c:20,d:30";
System.out.println("Original String: \"" + mixedString + "\"\n");

String[] mStringArray= mixedString.split(",");
String[] alphaArray = new String[mStringArray.length];
int[] numericArray = new int[mStringArray.length];

for (int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length; i++) {
    String[] tmp = mStringArray[i].split(":");
    alphaArray[i] = tmp[0];
    numericArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
}

// Display contents of the two Arrays
System.out.println("Elements From Alpha Array");
for (int i = 0; i < alphaArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(alphaArray[i]);
}

System.out.println("\nElements From Numeric Array");
for (int i = 0; i < numericArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(numericArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "a:10,b:15,c:20,d:30";
    // extract all numbers (All elements are numbers so you can convert it to int easily )
    String[] requiredArray1 = extractAllAccordingToRegex("\\d+", myString);
    // extract all characters        
    String[] requiredArray2 = extractAllAccordingToRegex("[a-zA-Z]+",myString);
    }

   static String[] extractAllAccordingToRegex(String inputRegex, String input) {
    List<String> extractedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern reg = Pattern.compile(inputRegex);
    Matcher m = reg.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        extractedItems.add(m.group());
    }
    return extractedItems.toArray(new String[1]);
    }
```